# How to respect checked box order in array (php and mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have fetched the latest 50 articles from my database using $wpdb. Then I have extracted titles with links and put them in a form with checkboxes. When I select checkboxes and push them in an array, the order of selected items is not the same as the order of selection, but it follows the order of the html document.

Is there a way to preserve the "checking order"?

This is my code:

```
<?php

    define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
    require('wp-load.php');

    $rooturl = 'https://magliadellasalute.com/';
    $articoli = isset($_POST['articoli']) ? $_POST['articoli'] : array();

    $result = $wpdb->get_results ("
        SELECT *
        FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts
        WHERE post_status = 'publish'
            AND post_type = 'post'
        ORDER BY ".$wpdb->prefix."posts.post_date DESC
        LIMIT 50;
    ");
?>

<table>

    <tr>

        <td>

            <form method="post" action="prova.php">

              <?php

                foreach ($result as $results) {

                    $titolo = $results->post_title;
                    $posthref = $rooturl.$results->post_name;

                ?>

                <input type="checkbox" name="articoli[]" value="<?php echo '*'.$titolo.'*'.'<br>Leggi '.$posthref ?>"/><?php echo $titolo.'<br><br>';

                }

              ?>

              <input type="submit" value="Invia il modulo"/>

            </form>

        </td>

        <td>

            <?php

                foreach ($articoli as $articolo) {
                    echo $articolo.'<br><br>';
                }

            ?>

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What order do you want? What order are you getting? Give examples.

Comment: @Martin I have 5 elements in this order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I check the boxes in this order: 3, 2, 1, 5, 4. When I echo the array, the order is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but I want 3, 2, 1, 5, 4. You can test it here: http://magliadellasalute.com/prova.php . Just check the boxes random, then submit. You can see that the order changes.

Comment: For something like this to work you would need to use JS to save order of cheeking and make on by one SQL request or at least array by wanted order, in order words not worth the trouble if you ask me. And if there is other way it is not simple, and I doubt you will get simple answer if any to this.

Comment: @ikiK I was thinking about JS, but I don't want to rearrange the whole code. I thought I could store the items in a list and then add something like this (shorturl.at/amnU9). But you know, I feel it is not the right way haha

Comment: Maybe you could use JS to build the list /link with GET then submit it for search that would give you maybe an wanted order, i think. So click one item, ads first ?1nd-item to link, then second ?1nd-item?2nd-item etc, maybe it would work.

Comment: In short, just HTML and PHP can not follow the order of clicking in form I believe.

Comment: Well, not without a page refresh

Comment: @Strawberry I have just started learning php and I can't get exactly what you mean. Could you be more specific?